# How to do AND + OR query in ElasticSerch & Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to perform the Elastic equivalent to the following in SQL:

```
select * from Pets 
where type is 'cat'
and age > 10
and name in ("Barry", "Oscar", .....)
```

I have the following Java code:

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(elasticIndexName);
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("type", "cat"));
queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("age").from("10"));
queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("name", "Oscar"));
queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("name", "Barry"));
```

But, if I understand correctly, the last two "must" statements are contradicting each other.
I tried to use the "should" term but it seems to bring all the cat names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, you need to do it like this (i.e. use a `terms` query):

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(elasticIndexName);
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("type", "cat"));
queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("age").from("10"));
queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("name", "Oscar", "Barry"));
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of the term query, I think you should try this, it'll help you to get the best results.

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("type", cat));
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("age").gt(10));
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(String.join(" ", Arrays.asList("Barry", "Oscar"), name).type(Type.BEST_FIELDS));
```